# Override method from nested class that I'm extending

Tags: c++, inheritance, inner-classes

```
class A : public B {}

class B : public C {}

class C
{
 public :

     class D : public I<T1>
     {
         virtual void method() const;
     }; 

     class E : public I<T2>
     {
         virtual void method() const;
     }; 

     class F : public I<T2>
     {
         virtual void method() const;
     }; 
 public :
     D d;
};
```

I would like in class A to override 'method' in class D. Is it possible?
I always get the message :

error: cannot define member function 'method' within 'A'

Comment: `A` does not inherit from `D`. Please show the code that produces the error message and the full message

Comment: @JacekCz tries looks like virtual void C::D::method() (in A)

Comment: C++ does not have "inner" classes with whatever Javaesque implications that may have. It has nested classes, and there is no inherent connection between the type of a nested class and the type of the class that it is nested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not possible, because `D` is just an inner class, `A` doesn't derive from it.

It's exactly the same as if `D` was defined outside of `C`, you cannot override functions that aren't part in some way of the base class (in this case, `A` doesn't derive from `D` in any way).

```
//How would A override a method in D? It can't, A has nothing to do with D
class A : public B {};
class B : public C {};
class C {}
class D { virtual void method() const {} }
```

Comment: So the only way is to check the Type of the class inside D, to change the behavior of the method?

Comment: @Lorac sorry, I don't understand exactly what you are asking. You could make A inherit from D, or move `method` in C.

Comment: I can't move method into C because in C, I have about 15 Inner classes with the method : 'method'

Comment: @Lorac Then make A inherit from D, if that is possible. Or just rename `method` :)

Comment: @Rakette class D extends a templated Class, and I can't make A inherit from D because that wouldn't make sens in the current code.

Comment: @Lorac then sorry, I don't see I way, maybe someone else more knowledgeable knows? Or you could ask a separate question, illustrating every problem you have

Comment: updated the code to reflect better the reality of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

A does not seem to inherit from D, perhaps class A : public C::D will achieve what you desire. C does not inherit D, it defines the class within itself so base classes don't have access to this derived entity.

edit: fwiw though this is a dangerous pattern of inheritance